# Boostrap navbar mega-menu dropdown circular shape

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, css-transitions

I am trying to open `submenu` items on hover but all the `submenus` to show at once. If user hover over the Navmenu bar it just drops down, and with additional social links.

```
.navbar-nav:before
{
    background-color: #000;
    top: -22px;
    right: -30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 110%;
    content: "";
}
```

I have tried to make `navbar-nav` positioned relative and added a pseudo element `:before` to dropdown when hover. But with this solution I have to tell the height of the pseudo element.

Secondly I tried, setting a whole new element with all the menu items but the sync is not matched, like I want to highlight the submenu items on hover the parent menu item.

HTML ( I am not sure if adding social icons here would work, or any suggestion)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Oracle Business Accountants">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
              
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</span></a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="sub-menu-item">
                          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Our Team</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-item">
                          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Our Team</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Business Solutions</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                          <li class="sub-menu-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Start Up Accounting</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="sub-menu-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Small Business Accounting</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="sub-menu-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Enterprise Accounting</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                          <li class="sub-menu-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Business Advisory</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="sub-menu-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Accounting & Taxation</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="sub-menu-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Bookkeeping</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="sub-menu-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Business Structuring</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="sub-menu-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">SMSF</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="sub-menu-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Tax Planning & Minimalisation</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Success Stories</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="tel:07 5607 0820" class="nav-link callnow">
                          <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
                          07 5607 0820
                        </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                  </form> -->
                </div>
            </nav>
```

I have this:

[image]

On hover want like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you please share with us your code!

Comment: need to share code

Comment: I have updated the question with HTML and CSS. Basically CSS is opening the pseudo element on hover.

Comment: Have you tried fontawesome?